# MUC with roundcube-mail converse.js plugin

Tags: xmpp, roundcube

We are using the converse.js based plugin for roundcube-mail which can be found  [here](https://github.com/priyadi/roundcube-converse.js-xmpp-plugin) for XMPP communication.

Chatting works fine as do chatrooms. When we initially log-in the servername for chat-rooms is set to conference.xmpp.mydomaine.com. However login out and back in does not preserve this setting and the server-field is always blank.
The rc-plugins allows to modify the config object that is passed to converse.js. We found settings to hide the server field, but no config that allows to specify a fixed URL for the chat-rooms.

Does anyone know how to tell converse.js and/or the rc-plugin that the url to the chatrooms is a fixed url?

Our setup:
* Ubuntu 14.04
* Ejabberd
* Apache 2.4 (fgcgi wrapper)
* roundcube-mail (in front of dovecot in front of open-ldap)
* roundcube-converse.js-xmpp-plugin

XMPP (Single-User chat + Multi-User-Chat) both works fine with jitsi and other clients. To be clear, chatting also works with converse.js, it just "looses" the server-url for the chat-rooms after the first login.

Thanks in advance for your time.